# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Toy' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm new to python OOP and I'm struggling with figuring out my error in this code, if anyone can help that would be great!

```
class Toy:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    def SetPrice(self, p):
        self.__price = p

    def GetPrice(self):
        return(self.__price)

    def InsertionSort(x):

        for index in range(1, len(x)):
            value = x[index].GetPrice()
            i = index -1
            while i >= 0:

                if value < (x[i].GetPrice()):
                    x[i+1].SetPrice(x[i])  
                    x[i].SetPrice(value)
                    i = i -1
                else:
                    break

prices = []
prices.append(Toy(200))
prices.append(Toy(10))
prices.append(Toy(20))

Toy.InsertionSort(prices)
```

but when I run it I get back this, but I don't really understand what the error means and I've tried writing it other ways but I'm not sure what to do now.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\testId.py", 
line 34, in <module>
Toy.InsertionSort(prices)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\testId.py", 
line 20, in InsertionSort
if value < (x[i].GetPrice()):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Toy'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: interesting one tbh thought it was just the usual syntax errors. lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is because the line

```
x[i+1].SetPrice(x[i])
```

sets `x[i+1]` to `x[i]` which is a `Toy`, not an int.

Comment: Thank you so much!